Finding the shortest distance and time for it using relative velocity
Two airplanes A and B flies with constant velocities in the same height as 300 km/h  to the direction which makes an angle $\alpha$ to the west from north and 400 km/h to the west respectively, here $\alpha = \arcsin\left(2/3\right)$ at a certain moment, the airplane A situates 90 km away from B in the south.

Find the velocity of B relative to A, Hence using that find the shortest distance between the 2 airplanes the time taken to occur that incident.

My Approach:
$v(A,E)=-300\sin\alpha \underline i+ 300\cos\alpha \underline j =-200\underline i + 100\sqrt5 \underline j\\
  v(B,E)=-400\underline i$
$v(B,A) = v(B,E)-v(A,E) \\
 v(B,A)=-200\underline i-100\sqrt 5 \underline j \\
|v(B,A)| = \sqrt{200^2 +5 \times100^2} = 300 kmh^{-1}$
but the problem arises when i try to find the shortest distance, this was in an applied math paper so i cant use differentiation, im not allowed to use the i,j notation too for some reason but i used here for the ease. without those two i somehow need to find the shortest distance and the time taken for it, but how to?
my second question. when i asked this from ChatGPT he solved it using the formula
$$d=\frac{|v(B,A) \times r(B,A)|}{|v(B,A)|} \\
t= \frac{|r(B,A)|}{|v(B,A)|} $$
where $r(B,A)$ is the relative displacement vector, which is $-90 \underline i + 0 \underline j$. by applying these values to the formula as
$$d=\frac{|(-200 \underline i - 100\sqrt5 \underline j)\times (-90\underline i + 0\underline j)|}{|300|} = \frac{18000}{300} = 60km \\
t= \frac{90}{300} = 0.3 hours$$
which did give a nice value though i don't know weather that value is the correct answer, but if it is, where did this formula come from? can anyone please derive it? we only have done dot product but this appears to be a cross product, so i have not much knowledge on it

I find it interesting that ChatGPT gives you a correct formula for $d$, but the formula for $t$ is only valid when $\vec r_{AB}$ and $\vec v_{AB}$ are parallel. You can tell it can't be true in general because, according to the formula, $t=0$ only when $\vec r_{AB}=0$, and it certainly is possible for the planes to be at their closest with actually crashing into each other.

exactly the reason why i posted this question, couldn't trust GPT with advanced questions

I'm a little puzzled by the wording. Assume that plane A has a speed of 300 km/h and
flies approximately NNW, that plane B has a speed of 400 km/h and flies W. Use a simple
Cartesian system where x points E and y points N. At time t=0 plane A is at (0,0)
and plane B is at (0,90 km). The coordinates of B are
$$(B_x,B_y)=(-t 400 km/h, 90 km)$$,
the coordinates of A are $$(A_x,A_y)=(-t \sin\alpha 300 km/h,t\cos\alpha 300 km/h)$$.
To minimize the distance we minimize the squared distance. The difference
of the two positions is
$$
(B_x-A_x,B_y-A_y) = (-t 400 km/h+t\sin\alpha 300 km/h, 90 km-t\cos\alpha 300 km/h).
$$
The squared distance is
$$
D^2(t) = (-400 t +300 t\sin\alpha)^2+(90-300t\cos\alpha)^2
=(250000-240000\sin\alpha)t^2-54000\cos\alpha t +8100,
$$
where time is measured in hours and distance in kilometers.
To minimize this value (find the apex of that parabola) set the first derivative to zero, $dD/dt=0$:
$$
2(250000-240000\sin\alpha)t-54000\cos\alpha=0
$$
which gives
$$
t=\frac{54000\cos\alpha}{500000-480000\sin\alpha}.
$$
Here $\sin\alpha=2/3$ and $\cos\alpha = \sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha} = \sqrt 5/3$.
Inserted into the previous equation the time of closest approach ist
$$
t=\frac{54000\cos\alpha}{500000-480000\sin\alpha}=\sqrt 5/10 \approx 0.2236.
$$
At that point $D^2(t)=3600$, so the distance is 60 km.

yes considering the whole problem in a Cartesian plane and appling coordinate geometry with derivatives to get the shortest distance and time is also a way, but since my professor wouldn't accept that answer i didnt even try it. now that i think of it, this problem might not be solvable without either using calculus or vectors... thank you either way

This can be done in a much more elementary way. It seems that this is what is intended, because the "coincidence" that $300\sin\alpha=\frac12\cdot 400$ means that your basic relative velocity triangle is isosceles, so the relative speed $v=300$ kph. After using parallel lines, you can determine that the angle between the relative velocity and due South is also $\alpha$.

It was a bit tricky doing this in Desmos because $\alpha \approx 45^o$, so there are angles in the diagram that look like right angles but aren't. $\beta \equiv (90^o-\alpha)$, so there are a number of actual right angles.
Now you know the angle of relative velocity to displacement, you can use the fact that the shortest path from a point to a line is perpendicular to the line.

So $$d=90\sin\alpha = 60 \text{ kph}$$
and. $$t = \frac {90\cos\alpha}v=\frac {\sqrt {5}} {10} \text{ hr}$$
